# Can't run python migrate on heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I've already run the following commands but I still can't update my migration successfully.

$ heroku run python manage.py makemigrations

$ heroku run python manage.py migrate

[image: error message on terminal]

Comment: Please post your error message as text instead of an image!

Answer (score 2):

Don't run `makemigrations` on Heroku. Its [ephmeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) will lose the generated files on the next restart. Plus, creating migrations in production isn't a very good idea.

Instead, run it on your local machine, apply the migrations with `migrate` and make sure they do what they should, then commit the generated files to your repository. Push to Heroku and run `migrate` there as well.